# Guidance on String replace query

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm trying to programmatically replace deprecated HTML with a new shortcode in a WP_Posts > post_content table.

The objective:

Replace

```
<span class="dropcap">%</span>
```

with

```
[dropcap class='post-dropcap']%[/dropcap]
```

where % is whatever character is in the row

There's another kicker: I need to find the string position of where that code starts, so that I can put the new string in the same starting position, as there's content before this string pattern. I also need to store the character % for each row, as each row has a different character based on the word it's typing.

I'm assuming I need to get the strpos() of the '<' of the matching string.

Then, I can store the value between the tags in an alias.

Then, I need to remove the matching string, and replace it with the new code, using the alias to reference the character that was removed prior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the `%` value by doing:

```
select substring_index(substring_index(col, '<', -1), '>', 1) as central_value
```

You can then concatenate to get what you want:

```
select concat('[dropcap class=''post-dropcap'']',
              substring_index(substring_index(col, '<', -1), '>', 1),
              '[/dropcap]'
             )
```

Answer (score 0):

As of MySQL 8 you should be able to use `REGEXP_REPLACE` for such task.

In each HTML line you'd be looking for the string `'<span class="dropcap">(.)</span>'` where the point stands for any character and the parentheses are there to remember this content.

You'd replace with `'\[dropcap class=''post-dropcap''\]\\1\[/dropcap\]'`, where `\\1` stands for the character we just remembered.

```
update html_lines
set line = regexp_replace(line, '<span class="dropcap">(.)</span>',
                                '\[dropcap class=''post-dropcap''\]\\1\[/dropcap\]')
```

This works for multiple occurences of the string in a line, too.

Comment: So if I were adding this to query only a table of a specific index, would I do this?

SELECT post_content FROM cdb_posts?

Comment: I don't understand the question. You can do an update as shown or only select this and leave the table as is. That would be `select regexp_replace(…) from tablename`. Does that answer your question?

Comment: OH, so update is the keyword that actually *acts* on the regex? I just don't really understand SQL that much. Thanks!

I just need the replace the strings on the content in post_content table of the cdb_posts index.

Comment: Well, that sucks. I just realized that my version of MySQL is locked at 5.X, so the regexp_replace doesn't exist. :(

Comment: Sorry to hear that. As to `UPDATE` / `SELECT`: `UPDATE` updates rows in a table and changes them. `SELECT` merely selects data from tables; the data in the tables stays the same. So use `UPDATE` when you consider `<span class…>` wrong and want to replace it with `[dropcap…` for good.

Comment: I'm assuming that there's no method for capturing wildcards and updating it without a rigorous series of commands?

Comment: You are right; without regex you'll have to use multiple string functions.

Comment: Is there nothing that captures based on it's relative position to a matched string? I think the RIGHT() function? So basically I can split it at the character, use offset 1 of the index of the last character of the first part of the matched string, then delete those as well as the second half matched string.

Then, you write an update that starts with the first half dropcap, then prints the captured character, then updates the second half. Does that even remotely make sense, or am I nuts? hahaha

Comment: With a maximum of one occurence per line, you'd look for '<span class="dropcap">'. From this position you can calculate the positions of all substrings. It's not very complicated. Only not as elegant as a single rexexp_replace, as you need several string functions in combination.

Comment: Is there any resource that you can point me to that would elucidate me? Thanks!

Comment: Well, Gordon Linoff already posted an answer which you can build upon. And if you simply google "mysql 5 string functions" you get here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html. Just see what's available and then apply those functions.

Comment: Alright, I'll take a look and figure out how to chain commands. Thanks!